# Updating values in table2 using table1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having two tables, `table1` having three columns (`id,names,salary`) and `table2` having three columns(`id,names,totalsalary`). I want to update `table2` `totalsalary` column by using `table1`. Please, find the below attachment of tables in images

[image: enter image description] 
[image: here]

Comment: There isn't anything even resembling a question here. You mention two tables. Then you have a picture of a result set which must be one of the two tables. Where is the other table? But even more importantly, what do you want to do. All you have done is said you have two tables.

Answer (score 1):

You could do inner join both tables and update totalsalary column on table2 using salary column from table1

```
update t2
set t2.totalsalary = t1.salary * 12 (Some calculation if needed)
from table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to `UPDATE` the `salary` value in `table2` with the sum of the salaries in `table1`. The most straight forward way to do this is with a sub-query and a `JOIN`.

The sub-query:

```
SELECT
  id,
  SUM(salary) as TotalSalary
FROM
  table1;
```

And then the `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE t2
SET
  salary = t1.TotalSalary
FROM
  table2 AS t2
JOIN
 (SELECT
    id,
    SUM(salary) as TotalSalary
  FROM
    table1
 ) AS t1
    ON t1.id = t2.id;
```